# How the loop the data background video in Reveal.js?

Tags: html, video, background, reveal.js

I am having several videos in a Reveal.js presention added like this:

`<section data-background-video="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.slid.es/site/homepage/v1/homepage-video-editor.mp4,https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.slid.es/site/homepage/v1/homepage-video-editor.webm">
</section>`

Everything looks as it should, but i want to loop some of the videos for mood in the background. I can not find any data attribute for looping data background videos. What is the best way to do it? Im having strange issues putting normal video tags in it and make it display fullscreen with css. ( described here [Fullscreen Video with CSS](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video)). Any ideas for Reveal.js ?

Comment: Actually i asked @hakimei on twitter and he told me the data-background-video-loop attribute is in the current dev version of reveal.js and will be in the next release.

Answer (score 6):

I just checked and in the latest release (Reveal.js 3.1.0) you can do: 
`data-background-video-loop="loop"` and the video will loop.

Comment: To be clear, the resulting section tag should look like: `<section data-background-video="video-here.mp4" data-background-video-loop="loop">`

Comment: And for markdown, put this comment on a line before the slide title/first line, and it will apply to the `section` tag: `<!-- .element: data-background-video="video-here.mp4" data-background-video-loop="loop" -->`